# open telemetry buckets not working (js)- every time creates new bucket

Tags: node.js, open-telemetry

im trying to use buckets in open telemetry histogram.
created a histoigram , and it sends data and all good,
but i cant make it aggregate data to the buckets.

im previewing the data in grafana , and every time a new value gets there , a new buckets is created.

also tried to use aggregator , but its not clear how its connected to the histogram.
because when running "accumulator.record()" the value is not shown

im using node with js

tried:

code:

```
const meterProvider = new MeterProvider({
    resource: new Resource({'service.name': 'my-express-app'}),
    views: [
        // override the bucket boundaries on `my.histogram` to [0, 50, 100]
        new View({ aggregation: new ExplicitBucketHistogramAggregation([0, 50, 100]), instrumentName: 'my.histogram'}),
        // rename 'my.counter' to 'my.renamed.counter'
        new View({ name: 'my.renamed.counter', instrumentName: 'my.counter'})
    ],
});

const metricExporter = new OTLPMetricExporter({
    url: "http://otel-collector:4317"
});

const metricReader = new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: metricExporter,
    exportIntervalMillis: 60000,
});
meterProvider.addMetricReader(metricReader);

const histogram = meter.createHistogram('histogram3',
    {
        description: 'description 2',
        unit: 'my.histogram'
    });

app.post('/histogram-value/:value', (req, res) => {
    const value = parseInt(req.params.value);

    
    const aggregator = new HistogramAggregator([1, 10, 100], true);
    

    histogram.record(value, {value: value});

    console.log('histogram.record: ', value)

    res.send(`histogram-test ${value}`);
});
```

but it didnt work, every time a new value got